# What English words can not be motivated and are arbitrary?

Tags: semantics, theoretical-linguistics

[What is the evidence for the arbitrariness of the sign?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/what-is-the-evidence-for-the-arbitrariness-of-the-sign/32188#32188)

Continuing this question, what English words can not be motivated and should be considered arbitrary?

I think only the natural meanings would remain and that all words that are compounds of those natural sounds. But what does the linguistic community think? Which words are 100% arbitrary and please say why?

Comment: What does it mean for a word to be "motivated"?

Comment: It sounds like you could look up the basic ideas behind the principle of arbitrariness and find lots of examples in textbooks that refer to it. Any reason why this is not helpful?

Comment: They’re all arbitrary and they’re all motivated. They’re arbitrary because they are symbols, unrelated in medium and form to what they represent, except in the arcane machine that is the human mind. They’re all motivated because they’re a sum of human physiology which can’t be subverted for this purpose, mediated through millennia of uncountably many invisibly small accidents of history, too long and too deep to ever capture. The summary of the audits of the development of these arbitrary signs are called *etymology*. Every word has one, whether we have access to it or not.

Comment: Perhaps you may find this article useful https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ae36/755aebf3bed256eaab5c6ad1c5cc3f4f594e.pdf (On the Arbitrary Nature of Linguistic Sign), the first thing I saw after googling it. This is basic, intro material covered in Linguistics 101.

Comment: I know you raise this because of the reaction to your methods, so I’ll sum up the linguistic community’s position on those: that you say historical linguistics is limited and not wholly adequate for its purpose, relying on necessarily scant written evidence: uncontroversial. A wish for additional reliable methods: shared. Some of the methods you raise: interesting, with a glaring caveat. The caveat: the reason the linguistic community relies on written evidence is *this is the only **testable** method we have about historical events*. None of your ideas are *testable*.

Comment: There is no way, using the methods you promote, to distinguish between *fact* and *fiction*. All your *results* have equal epistemic status: unvarnished speculation. On your *specific results*, never more than raw speculation, and often at odds with the *actual* data we have *specifically used* to discriminate fact from fiction. Until you solve the problem of falsifiability of your methods, they will never get traction, and you won’t get the audience you want in the linguistic community.

Answer (score 2):

> Which words are 100% arbitrary and please say why?

In some ways, none of them. In other ways, all of them.

In the question you linked, I used  = `/kæt/` as an example of an arbitrary word. But in many ways, it's not arbitrary at all. I call  a `/kæt/` because my parents called it a `/kæt/`, and my teachers called it a `/kæt/`, and their parents called it a `/kæt/`, and so on. Go far enough back and they called it a `/katte/`, and even farther back a `*/kattuz/`, and so on, and we can track the specific sound changes that eventually led to this becoming the modern English word that we all know.

That is, I didn't just one day decide on a whim that this small furry animal would be a `/kæt/`. I call it a `/kæt/` based on centuries upon centuries of oral transmission from generation to generation.

Now, why did my distant Proto-Germanic ancestors (I'm sure I had some somewhere in the family tree…) decide to call  a `*/kattuz/`? Unknown. Some linguists think it was borrowed from an Afro-Asiatic language, or a Uralic language, or some unknown substrate that's long since died out, or that it goes back to an obscure PIE root. There must have been *some* reason, but **there's just not enough surviving evidence to say**. This is the same reason we can't reliably talk about anything older than Proto-Indo-European: we can hypothesize and speculate, but there's not enough evidence to make **falsifiable theories**. And that's the standard that all modern science is weighed against.

The standard assumption is that there's nothing inherently -like about `/kæt/`, which is why  has different names all over the world (in Kenya it's a `/paka/`, in Japan it's a `/neko/`, and so on). That's what people mean when they talk about "the arbitrariness of the sign". But there's no origin of language we can point to to say "this, this is where the arbitrariness comes in". We can just say "if language weren't arbitrary, we'd expect to see all languages across the world having similar words for similar things, and we don't see that".

It sounds like what you're interested in is—*is there a built-in mechanism in our brain that somehow associates  with `/kæt/`?* In other words, is there an intrinsic meaning to the phonemes `/k/`, `/æ/`, `/t/` that connects them to ? And as you can see from the answers to my other question, the answer is pretty solidly no. This can be tested and falsified: take a large sample of people who don't know anything about language X (or its relatives), then show them the language-X words for  and , and see if they can identify which is which. It's been found that people with no outside knowledge of language X or its relatives usually **do no better than random guessing**.

(For an example you can try yourself: `/toːtoːtɬ/` is an attested word for a certain type of animal that I'm sure you're familiar with. Can you tell me what animal that is? How about `/tokatɬ/`? Or `/mit͡ʃin/`?)

**However…**

While people can't reliably tell  and  apart, there **are** some interesting results showing that **humans, regardless of language, do associate certain sounds with certain qualities**. Several different experiments have shown that people tend to associate words like *kiki*, *takete*, and *Kate* with sharp, pointy shapes, and words like *bouba*, *maluma*, and *Molly* with soft, rounded shapes.

This implies that there is some sort of intrinsic association between sound and quality embedded in the human brain. It's not anywhere near as strong as you've suggested (which is why people can't reliably distinguish  and  in an unknown language), but it does exist.

Could such an association have been involved in the origins of human language itself, millennia and millennia ago?

Sure! Absolutely! That's entirely possible. **But**—and this is an important "but"—that's so far in the past that no current linguistic models can make any sort of falsifiable claims about it. And as long as the claims aren't falsifiable, they're not considered science.

If you want to seriously pursue this idea, and take it in a more scientific direction, I'd recommend changing your approach. If you think that a certain phoneme is associated with a certain meaning, turn that into a falsifiable hypothesis: "humans, regardless of language, will instinctively associate phoneme X with meaning Y". Then set up an experiment that could falsify that hypothesis: gather a bunch of test subjects who speak English and a bunch who speak Mandarin, have them categorize pictures based on nonsense-word labels, and see if the accuracy is the same regardless of native language. This might support your theory, or might disprove it, but either way, **you'll have a falsifiable theory, and hard evidence one way or another**. And that's what modern science demands—nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Japanese Neko is cognate to Chinese 啮齿. It shows what the cat catches.

Comment: Draconis you wrote: “(which is why people can't reliably distinguish  and  in an unknown language)” With my methods I find the quality of the animal’s observed behaviour origin or use for humans. This goes for cat, dog, cow, Pferd, Giraffe, fly. A cat catches rodents. So in some languages the animal is named after his behaviour (catching) and in others it is after ‘rodents’. It is a signifier useful as an identifier for Japanese who bought a cat, had no word for it but knew what to use it against. Trade is Great!

Comment: There is a science named antropology. Books will give you limited information on words. Look at history, look at behaviour of humans. If we introduce an animal, that we don’t have a name for yet, what influence the name? A Jesus lizzard??? Think! Why is this lizzard called a Jesus lizzard? Because he heads the sick, is the Son of God or walks on water? Either motivation can relate to the animal randomly but one of the three is understood  by a large group of humans. Know the culture and you learn the words better. Including auch knowledge is scientific.

Comment: @Ajagar In that case, can you tell me (without looking it up) what those three words I listed mean? What the animals are, what they do, etc?

Comment: The falsifiabity you look for is too limited. That is not science. Science pushes the limits, finds new ways to interpret data. Looks for dialogue if there are new ideas and does not try to another it. Anyone who smothers progress by succes or failure is an enemy of true science. There is comfort in going with the accepted views and building a reputation and career on that but it corrupts and if makes you have to defend the views that get older and older until they crack under new and overwhelming evidence.

Comment: @Ajagar Re cat~catch: the etymologies of both of these words are well-attested, with plenty of evidence of every stage of their development. A few thousand years ago (in Latin), the former was _cattus_, and the latter was _capiō_, with no obvious relationship.

Comment: @Ajagar "The falsifiabity you look for is too limited. That is not science." On the contrary: falsifiability is the cornerstone of modern science. Anything that cannot be falsified is not science. Pushing the limits is all well and good, but when you say "…and also I refuse to accept any evidence that proves me wrong", you've stopped doing science.

Comment: If every name possible for cat in different languages can be linked to a description of its behaviour, its use for humans or its geographic origin, would that be proof? Or would modern science succumb if this can be done for dog too? Or also for cow. Or lion? When does empirical evidence become proof?

Comment: @Ajagar As soon as you have a falsifiable theory. That's the dividing line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97544/discussion-between-ajagar-and-draconis).